# Maven project can't find dependency when deploy on Google Cloud Build

Tags: maven, pom.xml, google-cloud-build, parent-pom, google-artifact-registry

I will try to be brief

My problem is that Cloud Build is not looking for the parent of my project where it should. I explain what I have installed:

On the one hand, I have a Maven project of type "POM" uploaded in Artifact Registry. This project is successfully uploaded as I have been able to use it as a dependency in my current project

[image]
[image]

On the other hand, I have a Maven project with Spring Boot, which uses the project uploaded to Artifact Registry as parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>blorks.corp</groupId>
    <artifactId>pom-repo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
```

The problem is that although I am able to use the dependency if I start my project on my PC, when I try to deploy it using Cloud Build it is not able to find the dependency

When I build my app on my PC, I can see in the console that the parent is being downloaded from the Artifact Repository

[image]

But when I try to deploy the app using Cloud Build, instead of looking for the dependency in the Artifact Repository, it looks for it in the Maven central repository

> I upload my project code to Bitbucket, and Cloud Build tries to build the "master" branch of my bitbucket repository

[image]

To give more information, I put the POM file of the project that I try to deploy

```
<parent>
    <groupId>blorks.corp</groupId>
    <artifactId>pom-repo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.artifactregistry</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactregistry-maven-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>artifact-registry</id>
        <url>artifactregistry://europe-west1-maven.pkg.dev/blorks-corp-gaming-wow/pom-repo</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>artifact-registry</id>
        <url>artifactregistry://europe-west1-maven.pkg.dev/blorks-corp-gaming-wow/pom-repo</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>artifact-registry</id>
        <url>artifactregistry://europe-west1-maven.pkg.dev/blorks-corp-gaming-wow/pom-repo</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>     
</repositories>

<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.artifactregistry</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactregistry-maven-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

I am a bit lost. I don't know where the error can come from... Maven? Cloud Build? Artifact Registry?

Comment: Is there any access issue, security, token, password to access to your repo? Did you try to activate the verbose logs with Maven to have more information?

Comment: @Daniel did my answer help you with your question ?

Answer (score 0):

To add packages to the repository, use `mvn deploy` and `mvn release`.

The Artifact Registry Wagon provider must be included in a core extensions file to correctly deploy a Maven project that references a parent, as indicated in the [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/authentication#auth-helper) requirements.

To upload assets created outside of Maven, use `mvn deploy:deploy-file`.

This sample command, for example, deploys example/external.jar and its project file example/pom.xml to the us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo repository.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
-Durl=artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo \
-DpomFile=example/pom.xml -Dfile=example/external.jar
```

When connecting to a repository with a third-party application, you must first authenticate with Artifact Registry.

You must use the [core extensions](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html) technique to ensure that Maven can identify parent POM files and plugins if your project needs to resolve these dependencies.

Create the file `$maven.projectBasedir/.mvn/extensions.xml̀ in your project with the following information. The wagon is defined by the extension> element.

```
 <extensions xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/core-extensions-1.0.0.xsd">
   <extension>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud.artifactregistry</groupId>
     <artifactId>artifactregistry-maven-wagon</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.4</version>
   </extension>
 </extensions>
```

Maven may now use Artifact Registry to resolve parent or plugin dependencies.